# SelectAll does not call Event Handler

Tags: javascript, html

Please see the JavaScript below:

```
<html>
<head><title></title></head>
<body>

<script type = "text/javascript">

function Test()
{
    alert('got here');
}

 function SelectAll() {
    var frm = document.forms[0];
    for (i = 0; i < frm.elements.length; i++) {
        frm.elements[i].checked=true;
            }
    }

</script>

<form>
<input type="checkbox" name="Test1" onClick="Test()"/>
<input type="checkbox" name="Test2" onClick="Test()"/>
<input type="checkbox" name="Test3" onClick="Test()"/>
<input type="checkbox" name="Test4" onClick="SelectAll()"/>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

The alert box appears if I click either: Test1, Test2 or Test3.   When I click Test4 I expect the alert to appear three times (once for Test1; once for Test2 and once for Test3).  However, this does not happen.  The event handler is not called at all.  Why is this?

How can I amend the HTML so that the event handler is called three times.

Comment: Setting the elements `checked`-property, does not invoke the click event.

Answer (score 0):

You need to trigger `onclick` also:

```
frm.elements[i].onclick();
```

To avoid last element from click you need to reduce length in for-loop by `1`, so final code should be:

```
function SelectAll() {
    var frm = document.forms[0];
    for (i = 0; i < ( frm.elements.length - 1 ); i++) {
        frm.elements[i].checked=true;
        frm.elements[i].onclick();
    }
}
```